# how to update two uitableviewcell in one tableview using reloadrowatindexpath

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I created  two uitableview cell in one UITableView. Each one has different elements.I am going to show  different contents by clicking UIbutton. The data filled on the UITableViewcell is coming from the server. So I am looking for how to update the two different cells using  reloadrowAtindex path rather  than tableview reload for performance.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Reloading TableView is not really a big issue. You have just two rows anyway.

Answer (score 0):

refer following code.

```
NSIndexPath* myIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:myRow inSection:mySection];
NSArray* myIndexPathModel = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myIndexPath, nil];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:myIndexPathModel withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```